# module.export and getting user information

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to display `client.user.avatarURL` in a command file through `module.export` using:

```
...
icon_url: client.user.avatarURL;
...
```

but when I call the command through the bot I have this error in the console:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'avatarURL' undefined`

I've tried getting the value of the client on a const and pass it true the command handler but didn't solve it as well. If you delete that line everything works fine, so I guess is just a wrong way to pass client informations.

main.js

```
const fs = require('fs');
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { prefix, token } = require('./config.json');

const client = new Discord.Client();
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();


const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Online!');
});

client.on('message', message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const commandName = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (!client.commands.has(commandName)) return;
    const command = client.commands.get(commandName);

    if (command.args && !args.length) {
        let reply = `You didn't provide enough arguments, ${message.author}!`;

        if (command.usage) {
            reply += `\nThe proper usage would be: \n\`${prefix}${command.name} ${command.usage}\``;
        }

        return message.channel.send(reply);
    }


    try {
        command.execute(message, args, client);
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        message.reply('there was an error trying to execute that command!');
    }
});

client.login(token);
```

and the command file:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'help',
    description: 'Help file',
    execute(message, client) {
        message.channel.send({ embed: {
            color: 0xf7da66,
            author: {
                name: 'Bot',
                icon_url: client.user.avatarURL,
            },
            title: 'commands guide',
            description: 'This is an discord bot.',
            fields: [{
                name: 'Command',
                value: 'Type: example.',
            },
            ],
            timestamp: new Date(),
            footer: {
                icon_url: client.user.avatarURL,
                text: '© Bot',
            } } });
    },
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing: `command.execute(message, args, client);` but then `execute(message, client) {` wich means that in your command file `client` is now actually the array `args`.

You need to do: `execute(message, args, client) {`

Comment: I just tried to solve it as you said, but after a while a found a solution as using ```message.client.user.avatarURL``` without needing to pass 'client' through the command handler. Thank you anyway

Comment: If your question is solved mark the answer with the green tick please

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `module.exports = (client, message, args) => {` instead.